# Mocking UnitOfWork/GenericRepository with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm running into an issue where Moq doesn't return what I excpect using following code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetResultReturnsAResult()
{
    var mockUnitOfWork = Arrange();
    // Arrange
    var controller = new ResultsController(mockUnitOfWork.Object);
    controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

    // Act
    var response = controller.GetResult(2);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(response is OkNegotiatedContentResult<Result>);
    var contentResult = response as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Result>;
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);
    Assert.IsTrue(contentResult.Content.ID == 2);
}

[TestMethod]
public void GetResultReturnsNotFound()
{
    var mockUnitOfWork = Arrange();

    // Arrange
    var controller = new ResultsController(mockUnitOfWork.Object);
    controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

    // Act
    var response = controller.GetResult(100);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(response is NotFoundResult);
    var contentResult = response as NotFoundResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
}

private Mock<IUnitOfWork> Arrange()
{
    var results = new List<Result>()
    {
        new Result()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "Result 1",
            Modified = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1),
            Created = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1),
            CreatedBy = "Tester 1",
            ModifiedBy = "Tester 2"
        },
        new Result()
        {
            ID = 2,
            Name = "Result 2",
            Modified = new DateTime(2017, 1, 2),
            Created = new DateTime(2017, 1, 2),
            CreatedBy = "Tester 1",
            ModifiedBy = "Tester 2"
        },
    };

    var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    var mockResultRepository = new Mock<IGenericRepository<Result>>();

    mockResultRepository.Setup(x => x.Get(null, null, ""))
        .Returns(results);
    mockResultRepository.Setup(x => x.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns((int id) => GetById(results, id));
    mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.ResultRepository)
        .Returns(mockResultRepository.Object);

    return mockUnitOfWork;
}

private Result GetById(List<Result> results, int id)
{
    return results.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ID == id);
}
```

In this case my TestMethods testing GetById both throw an exception with message: Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.

When I change the mocking code to this:

```
mockResultRepository.Setup(x => x.Get(null, null, ""))
    .Returns(results);
mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.ResultRepository)
    .Returns(mockResultRepository.Object);
mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.ResultRepository.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns((int id) => GetById(results, id));
```

The GetById tests don't throw an exception but GetResultReturnsAResult doesn't return a result so it always fails.

Can anyone shed a light on this behaviour?

Comment: I'd recommend you to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because most of the provided code is not relevant to the issue, while something actually required is probably missing. I mean replicate the issue without anything ASP specific and leave only the bare minimum in actual unittest, so that anyone can run it and get the same result as the one you are getting.

Comment: `mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.ResultRepository.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns((int id) => GetById(results, id));` should work, to be able to find the source of the problem please add the implementation of `controller.GetResult`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Eugene Podskal in the comments, I was creating an MCVE ([download here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36428399/TestIssue.zip)) and ran into the solution. He was in fact right that the solution was to be found in code that was not shared first.

The code that returned the

```
Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'
```

exception was correct in throwing this exception since

```
GetById
```

takes a

```
params object[]
```

as first parameter.